# Não consigo colocar cor de fundo em um "card" que estou fazendo usando swift (iOs App Dev Tutorials)

Tags: swift, apple

Boa tarde,

Comecei o curso gratuito da Apple iOs App Dev Tutorials para aprender swift porém em uma etapa do curso, mesmo validando tudo não consegui achar o que esta de errado.

A etapa que estou, preciso fazer um Card com o fundo amarelo porém o fundo não fica amarelo... Mesmo copiando o código do Layout pronto, não consigo resolver.
Quando baixo o arquivo e abro ele mostra amarelo normalmente.

Alguem pode me ajudar?

```
//CardView
import SwiftUI

struct CardView: View {
    let scrum: DailyScrum
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(scrum.title)
                .accessibilityAddTraits(.isHeader)
                .font(.headline)
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Label("\(scrum.attendees.count)", systemImage: "person.3")
                    .accessibilityLabel("\(scrum.attendees.count) attendees")
                Spacer()
                Label("\(scrum.lengthInMinutes)", systemImage: "clock")
                    .accessibilityLabel("\(scrum.lengthInMinutes) minute meeting")
                    .labelStyle(.trailingIcon)
            }
            .font(.caption)
        }
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(scrum.theme.accentColor)
    }
}

struct CardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var scrum = DailyScrum.sampleData[0]
    static var previews: some View {
        CardView(scrum: scrum)
            .background(scrum.theme.mainColor)
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 400, height: 60))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que esse `scrum.theme.mainColor` é o amarelo. Tenta ir até a raiz dessa propriedade, la onde está a `Color` e verifica se ela está correta.

Comment: Eu fui lá e verifiquei que está tudo correto também. O bizarro é que o código está literalmente igual o layout que o curso deixa mas mesmo assim não consigo alterar o background. Não sei mais o que fazer!